# certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --deploy-hook

Tags: server, letsencrypt

Installed certbot service via commands below;

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install certbot
```

Then run the command below to generate tls certificate, but got error message, how its fix?

```
root@sunucu:~# sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http \ --deploy-hook "systemctl restart coturn" \ -d mydomain.com
usage:
  certbot [SUBCOMMAND] [options] [-d DOMAIN] [-d DOMAIN] ...

Certbot can obtain and install HTTPS/TLS/SSL certificates.  By default,
it will attempt to use a webserver both for obtaining and installing the
certificate.
certbot: error: unrecognized arguments:  --deploy-hook systemctl restart coturn                                    -d mydomain.com
```

its ubuntu 18.04 version (bionic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslashes are intended for splitting input over multiple lines. If you use `\ --deploy-hook` or `\ -d` on a single line, you're adding a literal space to the option name.

So either use

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http \
  --deploy-hook "systemctl restart coturn" \
  -d mydomain.com
```

(note that `\` must be the very last character on the line - with no trailing whitespace) or just use a single line without backslashes.

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http --deploy-hook "systemctl restart coturn" -d mydomain.com
```